# MVC Validations on Ajax Post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, ajaxform

Iam using MVC4, i want to post my page from client to server, iam using ajax post method to post my submit my data.

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '/Admin/Create/',
                //data: JSON.stringify(datatosend),
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.redirectUrl != null) {
                    window.location = data.redirectUrl;
                    }
})
});
```

Here instead of `<input type="submit" value="add">` am using `<input type ="button" value="add" id="btn">`
and on click method to call ajax post. 
When am using submit type, validation are working fine, but on button type vaidations are not working and page is not redirecting after success also.
I have seen lot of posts regarding this issue. But not able to find out the reason

Answer (score 1):

In your `click` handler do something like:

```
var isValid = $(this).closest("form").validate();
if (isValid) {

    // do ajax post
}
```

Or, you can take a look at the documentation, it has a different approach:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Answer (score 0):

1 .To fire validation error you can do the following code.

```
$("#btn").click(function(){


var form = $("#myform").validate();

if(form.valid())
{
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '/Admin/Create/',
                //data: JSON.stringify(datatosend),
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.redirectUrl != null) {
                    window.location = data.redirectUrl;
                    }
                error: function (errorResponse) {
                    alert(errorResponse.responseText);
                    }
           })
}

});
```

2.Why your page is not getting redirected check few point .

- check you are returning Json result from you action as `JsonResult`.
- value should be in quotes `window.location = '';`